# MongoDB localhost "Upgrade Required" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hello I'm new to website development and I've been trying to create a forum page. For this I decided to use MongoDB (for the first time) but I'm having a few problems that I can't seem to get solved. For some reason the localhost url shows this "update required" message but I'm unsure on what and how I'd need to upgrade it.

Request URL:
http://localhost:3001/posts
Request Method:
OPTIONS
Status Code:
426 Upgrade Required

**Server.js**

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

client.connect().then(() => {
  const db = client.db('forumApp');
  const postsCollection = db.collection('posts');
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB");

  const app = express();
  const port = 3001;

  // Use a wildcard to allow any origin
  app.use(cors()); // Allow all origins to access the server

  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  app.get("/posts", async (req, res) => {
      try {
          console.log("Received GET request for /posts");
          const posts = await postsCollection.find().toArray();
          console.log("Sending posts:", posts);
          res.json(posts);
      } catch (err) {
          console.error("Error fetching posts:", err);
          res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred" });
      }
  });

  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
  });
});
```

**Frontend.js**

```
const postTitle = document.getElementById("postTitle");
const postText = document.getElementById("postText");
const postList = document.getElementById("postList");

postButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    const title = postTitle.value;
    const text = postText.value;
    
    if (title && text) {
        await createPost(title, text);
        postTitle.value = "";
        postText.value = "";
        fetchPosts();
    }
});

async function createPost(title, text) {
    await fetch("http://localhost:3001/posts", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ title, text }),
    });
}

async function fetchPosts() {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/posts");
    const posts = await response.json();
    displayPosts(posts);
}

function displayPosts(posts) {
    postList.innerHTML = "";
    posts.forEach(post => {
        const postElement = document.createElement("div");
        postElement.innerHTML = `
            <h2>${post.title}</h2>
            <p>${post.text}</p>
        `;
        postList.appendChild(postElement);
    });
}

fetchPosts();
```

I have tried a lot of things. I've even tried asking chatgpt and he thinks that the issue might be related to the server's CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) configuration. But that didn't help at all either so I've decided to come here and ask about it.

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/posts' from origin 'https://unsolved.ignorelist.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.